# Progress Dialog in Android

Tags: android

is it possible to add any layout in progress dialog box in android??

Comment: What layout would you like to add? If you're looking for much more than the default progress dialog, you should probably just create your own activity and display it as a dialog or use a different type of dialog. I imagine you probably shouldn't try to put a listview in a progress dialog

Answer (score 3):

The progress dialog currently implemented does not allow for custom content. Your best bet is to use the standard Dialog class and add in the progress bar and whatever else you need into a layout file and inflate it.

See [Dialogs in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)